# Mesh of scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot of a grain ( r theta phi / xyz). I'm working on python(3). I want to mesh it to have a convex body with connectivities beetween faces. Because of numerical problems, i think that i must use Delaunay Triangulation to have a convex body with triangles close to the equilaterals. I want to do a surfacic mesh from the 3D scatter plot. Is it possible with Delaunay ?

Otherwise, i tried to use the Convexhull3D (see the code). The problem is that i don't have triangles close to equilaterals and also i don't know how can i save my resulats (coordinates and connectivities). Is it possible to manage the triangles surface ? (like to have only equilaterals)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull


# 8 points defining the cube corners
pts = np.load('cart.npy') # cartesian coor of the scatter plot also have 
spherical coor

hull = ConvexHull(pts)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")

# Plot defining corner points
ax.plot(pts.T[0], pts.T[1], pts.T[2], "ko")

# 12 = 2 * 6 faces are the simplices (2 simplices per square face)
for s in hull.simplices:
    s = np.append(s, s[0])  # Here we cycle back to the first coordinate
    ax.plot(pts[s, 0], pts[s, 1], pts[s, 2], "r-")

# Make axis label
for i in ["x", "y", "z"]:
    eval("ax.set_{:s}label('{:s}')".format(i, i))

plt.show()
```

As resultats, i need a mesh convex body with coordinates and connectivities between it faces and with simplex close to equilaterals.